# Monoids where every two non-unit elements have a common power

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

> **Q1.** Is there any standard name for a (multiplicatively written) monoid $H$ with the property that, for all $x, y \in H \setminus H^\times$, there exist $m, n \in \mathbf N^+$ and $u, v \in H^\times$ such that $x^m = uy^n v$? Here, $H^\times$ is, as usual, the set of units (or invertible elements) of $H$.

A few examples of monoids with the above property: (a) groups; (b) *numerical monoids*, that is, submonoids of $(\mathbf N, +)$; (c) *Puiseux monoids*, i.e., submonoids of $(\mathbf Q_{\ge 0}, +)$.

> **Q2.** What about other *interesting* examples from the literature?

Of course, Puiseux monoids are more general than numerical monoids, but there are some good reasons for distinguishing them.

*Edit.* Benjamin Steinberg [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/266691/16537) that, if we require that, for all $x, y \in H$, there exist $m,n \in \mathbf N^+$ such that $x^m \mid_H y^n$ (i.e., if we drop the restriction about non-units), then what we get are the *archimedean monoids*. So, I should probably add that the reason for requiring $x, y \in H \setminus H^\times$ and $u,v \in H^\times$ in the above definitions, comes from the fact that I'm interested in the "structure" of the *system of sets of lengths* of $H$, that is, the family of sets 
$$
\mathscr{L}(H) := \{\mathsf L_H(x): x \in H\} \setminus \{\emptyset\} \subseteq \mathcal P(\mathbf N),
$$ 
where for a fixed $x\in H\setminus\{1_H\}$ we denote by $\mathsf L_H(x)$ the set of all $k \in \mathbf N^+$ for which there exist atoms $a_1,\ldots,a_k\in H$ such that $x=a_1\cdots a_k$, while $\mathsf L_H(1_H):=\{0\}$. So, in this context, $H$ is *interesting* only if $\mathscr L(H)$ is "rich" (in particular, $H$ should have at least one atom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the bit about restricting to non-units you get what is called an archimedean semigroup.

Comment: At least in (classical) factorization theory, a (multiplicatively written) *commutative* monoid $H$ is called *archimedean* if $\bigcap_{n \ge 0} a^n H = \emptyset$ for all $a \in H \setminus H^\times$, cf., e.g., Halter-Koch's book *Ideal Systems: An Introduction to Multiplicative Ideal Theory* (Ch. 3, Exercise 6). This, however, *seems* quite different from the property stated in the OP. On the other hand, if I get your answer correctly, you take a semigroup $H$ to be archimedean if, for all $x, y \in H$, there exist $m,n \in \mathbf N^+$ with $x^m = y^n$: In particular, (...)

Comment: (...) an archimedean monoid $H$ in the sense of this definition would have the property that, for all $x \in H$, there is $n \in \mathbf N^+$ with $x^n = 1_H$, and hence would be a group. But groups are not really interesting from the point of view of (classical) factorization theory. So I guess the restriction to non-units in the OP is what makes the difference here.

Comment: People allow noncommutative archimedean semigroups and it is the same as what you write of you ignore the restriction about non units. Otherwise there is no name.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I will wait to see if anyone can at least provide some interesting examples of monoids that satisfy the condition in the OP. If not, I will eventually accept your answer.

Comment: I don't know interesting examples. For a finite monoids this means the complement of the group of units I'd a nilpotent extension of a completely simple semigroup.

Comment: It is also satisfied in semigroups in which all elements generate the same two sided ideal.